# Split Numbers String to Integer Array

Tags: java, arrays, string, split, integer

String contains an unknown length of numbers which are seperated by "-", for example:

```
string = "4-12-103-250-302"
```

I need these numbers in an integer array like this:

```
intArray[] = { 4, 12, 103, 250, 302 }
```

Can you give me a code example/solution?

Comment: Sorry, i was talking about Java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the String.Split method in Java.

Then convert the Array to an Integer Array.

```
string str = "4-12-103-250-302";
String[] parts = string.split("-");

int[] intArray = new int[parts.length];

for(int i = 0; i < parts.length -1; i++)
{
    intArray[i] = Integer.parseInt(parts[i]);
}
```

Then you can just access all of the parts just as an array would work.

```
intArray[0]
intArray[1]
.
.
etc
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to split the string into an array by a character delimiter. Then you want to apply a function to each item in the array to make it into an integer.

In php:

```
<?php
$string = "4-12-103-250-302";
$aray = $string.split("-");
array_walk($aray, 'intval');
```

Other languages will have similar constructs.

Since Java < 8 doesn't have use lambdas, try this:

```
str = "4-12-103-250-302";
String[] straray = str.split("\\-", -1);
int[] intArray = new int[straray.length];
for (int i=0; i < straray.length; i++) {
    intArray[i] = Integer.parseInt(straray[i]);
}
```

Comment: Who said java 8 can't be used? And it's just a map, no reduce is necessary. I think you meant lambdas anyways

Comment: Indeed, yes I haven't had my coffee this morning.